# Problemas de conexão com PostgreSQL(URL fantasma)

Tags: java, postgresql, conexão

Estou trabalhando em um projeto java web e tenho uma classe de conexão com o banco PostgreSQL ,que liga a base de dados chamada **BASE_X** que teve o desempenho adequado, mas eu fiz uma cópia do projeto que possui essa classe e fiz um outro banco de dados no PostgreSQL idêntico ao banco anterior,apenas mudando o nome para **BASE_X1**.
Queria eu fazer umas novas experiências com o novo banco que não estava povoado como o antigo, eu mudei o nome da base de dados  na URL do caminho da classe de conexão para ir ao novo banco não povoado  e compilei todo o projeto junto com a classe.
Limpei o histórico do navegador,limpei a memória cache, desimplantei o projeto , e então rodei o novo projeto com o novo caminho e ele conectou com o antigo!!
Para tirar a dúvida peguei a classe que foi compilada e descompilei para verificar se havia algum erro mas nada ele estava indicando a conexão para o novo banco!!Nunca vi algo assim!! E já fiz essa experiência outras vezes com outros projetos não web e deram certo. Não sei  o que está acontecendo..

Parte do código da classe de conexão do primeiro projeto:

```
private Connection con;

private final Properties prop = null;

private final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/BASE_X";
```

Parte que mudei da classe de conexão do segundo projeto:

```
private final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/BASE_X1";
```

---

Código que faz a conexão:

```
package br.com.banco.basex.Connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import br.com.banco.basex.Excecoes.FonteDeDadosException;
import java.util.Properties;
public class Conexao implements ConexaoIF {

private Connection con;

private final Properties prop = null;

private final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/BASE_X";

public Conexao() throws SQLException {
    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "postgres", "doremifa");
    } catch (FonteDeDadosException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new FonteDeDadosException(
                        "Não foi possível conectar com o banco de dados!");
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() {

    return this.con;
}

public void closeAll(PreparedStatement stat) throws FonteDeDadosException {
    try {
        this.con.close();
        stat.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new FonteDeDadosException("Falha ao fechar conexões");
    }

}

public void closeAll(Statement stat) throws FonteDeDadosException {
    try {
        this.con.close();
        stat.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new FonteDeDadosException("Falha ao fechar conexões");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Bem provável que é outro lugar que faça essa conexão

Comment: @Jéferson Mas esse trecho de codigo que indica o caminho!

Comment: Poste o código em que você faz a conexão

Comment: É um projeto de servlert? vc não copiou e colou a pasta e renomeou o projeto?

Comment: @rray Sim existem servlets e jsp! ! Projeto Maven web!!

Comment: Essa classe não tem problemas !! O problema é o fato de quando o  projeto abre no  browser e eu preencho o form ele encaminha os dados para o banco povoado e não para  o novo!! Não tenho ideia do que está acontecendo! Até cheguei  a desinstalar o netbeans!!

Comment: Os projetos não tem o mesmo nome de context root(não lembre bem o nome exato) ?

Comment: @rray Como assim cara , META-INF.context.xml? Tem outro nome,essa parte eu não copiei, eu criei  um novo projeto e depois inclui as paginas e classes do antigo projeto, desculpe a demora não vi o seu  ultimo comentário!!!

Comment: aaah entendi, pensei que tinha copiado o projeto inteiro. então n deve ser o que eu falei.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca vi situação assim tão estranha!! As vezes esse tipo de episodio  acontece mesmo, talvez seja um "byte do alem", que quira zombar da nossa alta prosopopeia de cidadães programadores dignos e respeitados...

Solucionei o problema assim:

Já qu projeto antigo estava a contento , ele não é o problema , e parti então para o PostgresSQL e fiz a unica solução plausível:

Fiz **backup** do banco antigo **BASE_X** e deletei ele do PostgreSQL.
Foi tiro e queda , como o antigo não existia mais , ele conectou com o novo banco **BASE_X1** não povoado!!
Até mais!!